# Asking for Clarification on Regex Behavior of ^, *, +

Tags: python, regex

I apologize for the poorly worded question.

I have a large number of strings like:

> "ODLS_ND33283633__PS1185"

Which the first letters up to the first `"_"` are a header and the remainder (ND33283633__PS1185) is a unique ID.

I wrote a regex in python trying to remove everything up to the first `"_"` desiring

> "ND33283633__PS1185"

as the end result.

I figured something like:

```
.*_? or .+?_
```

Would do the trick, but that was not the case...

I kept trying to write various regex unsuccessfully to accomplish this and finally went online and found another person's answer I was able to use as an example to rewrite as:

```
^[^_]+_
```

Which gave me my desired result, but now I have questions which I can't figure out the answer for:

I found that removing the "^" at the front and writing it as:

```
[^_]+_
```

caused the regex to remove everything up to the second "_" so the resulting string was:

> "_PS1185"

I understand that `"^"` identifies as the beginning of the line, but I would like to know why not including it removes up to the second without the "^" at the front?

My understanding is that `[^_]+` matches characters NOT equal to `"_"` 1 or more number of times, so why would including the "^" at the beginning cause it to stop at the first, while excluding it causes it to stop at the second?

Another thing, when I replaced the `"+"` symbol with a `"*"`:

```
[^_]*_
```

I expected the same result but instead got:

> PS1185

I thought that `*` matches 0 or more, while `+` matches 1 or more, so they're effectively the same except + is supposed to be more 'strict'. However, seeing these results makes me feel like I don't fully understand how regex is behaving. Is there anyone here that can please explain what is actually going on?

Comment: `.+?` is **not** equal to `.*`...

Comment: When you remove `^` then `re.sub` is making 2 substitutions first `ODLS_` and then `ND33283633_`

Comment: @anubhava Yes, but why is the '^' being used to tell the regex to make 1 replacement versus 2? I thought '^' is only an identifier for the start of a line, not a condition for the number of replacements to be made.

Comment: `^` enforces that regex matches only starting `[^_]*_` not anywhere else in the input.

Comment: I see, so "^" is used as a 'match only the first case' condition in regex. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: in Perl I'd do something like this: `my $id = s/.*?_//;`. PCRE language-agnostic example: https://regex101.com/r/9w1R2Y/1/